# TryEnterCriticalSection

Tags: c++, windows, critical-section

I'm not sure if I correctly understand. `TryEnterCriticalSection` is called only once, it's not stick like `EnterCriticalSection`? 
E.g. if I write something like

```
if(TryEnterCriticalSection (&cs))
{
//do something that must be synh
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}
else
{
//do other job
}
//go on
```

and if `TryEnterCriticalSection` returns false the part `do something that must be synh` will never be done, and `do other job` part will be exucuted and then `go on`?

Comment: We usually call functions like `EnterCriticalSection` _blocking_. If they can't succeed immediately, the execution of code is _blocked_ and the function waits until the blocking condition is resolved. `TryEnterCriticalSection` is called _non-blocking_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed right. `TryEnterCriticalSection()` is called once, and tries to enter the critical section only once. If the critical section is locked, it returns false after the check.

In general, if a function returns a boolean or an int, the if/else clauses behaves like following:

```
if (function()) //function() is called once here, return result is checked
{
  //executed if function() returned true or non-zero
}
else
{
  //executed if function() returned false or zero
}
//executed whatever happens
```

Comment: maybe it's because my English suxx, the main question is if I correctly understand that TryEnterCriticalSection is called only once snd isn't stick like EnterCriticalSection

Comment: It is called only once, like any other function in `if(function())`. Do you mean you want to know if the critical section is checked only once? then yes.

Answer (score 6):

`TryEnterCriticalSection()` does the following:

- tries to enter a critical section
- if that section is currently grabbed by some other thread the section is not entered and the function returns zero, otherwise
- the section is entered and the function returns nonzero

Anyway the function never blocks. Compare it with `EnterCriticalSection()` that falls through if no other thread has the critical section entered and blocks if such other thread exists.

So the outcome of your code will depend on whether the critical section is entered by another thread at the moment the function is called. Don't forget to call `LeaveCriticalSection()` for each time when `TryEnterCriticalSection()` returns nonzero (succeeds).

So yes, your code is written with right assumptions.

Comment: maybe it's because my English suxx, the main question is if I correctly understand that TryEnterCriticalSection is called only once snd isn't stick like EnterCriticalSection

Comment: @Alecs: It can be called many times by one thread but it never blocks regardless of whether the critical section is grabbed by any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is correct.

See more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686857%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: maybe it's because my English suxx, the main question is if I correctly understand that TryEnterCriticalSection is called only once snd isn't stick like EnterCriticalSection

Answer (score 0):

If your critical section is too small, than you must try this `TryEnterCriticalSection` in a loop because it will then acquire less clock cycles to enter critical section and leave that critical section.